# Expo Permissions returns status of 'undetermined' in Production

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, expo

In my react native app which I ave published on the Google Play Store, I require Camera Roll permissions. This works during testing, but not in the published version of the app.

```
  getPermissionAsync = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    if (status !== "granted") {
      alert("Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!");
    }
    await this.setState({ permission: status === "granted" });
  };

  _pickMedia = async () => {
    if (this.state.permission != true) {
      await this.getPermissionAsync();
    }
    if (this.state.permission == true) {
        // get image
    }
  };
```

In testing this works as expected, asking permission to access the camera roll every time the user tries to upload a picture till its given. However in production, the user is prompted once for permission to use the camera roll and whether or not they allow it, the alert box comes up and the user is unable to pick an image. If they try to add media again, they aren't prompted for permissions and it just alerts again.

As per the expo docs I have added READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to my permissions in app.json:

```
    "android": {
      "permissions": ["READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"],
    }
```

Could someone tell me why this doesn't work in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realise that edits to parts of  `app.json` aren't updated for a published app by `expo publish` and you need to run `expo build` instead. The issue was  that I hadn't initially added `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to the permissions and when I did later I used `expo publish` to update the app. This meant the published version wasn't actually updated.  After running `expo build` now and generating a new app bundle, permissions started working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

it is not working in production becasue you did not add CAMERA permission.so, add `CAMERA` [permission](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/#android)

```
"android": {
      "permissions": ["CAMERA","READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"],
 }
```